# Do people still use "(I'm) your servant, sir/mam?" When they get introduced?

Tags: idioms, history

I was watching the TV series "Poldark" on Netflix and I've realized when someone introduces a gentleman, the guy says:

> Your servant, sir/ma'am

In which if the other person (if not a lady) responds with:

> And I, yours

This is very similar to my mother tongue but was the first time I've heard it in English. Is it an idiom that people still use? If yes, when do you use it? Would you laugh if someone said that to you?

Comment: No, it is very much _not_ an idiom that people still use (_Poldark_ is set more than 200 years ago). It would sound very quaint for someone to say it today.

Comment: @KateBunting - I might use jokingly expressions like these to one of my friends who is a big fan of (Doctor) Samuel Johnson (1709-1784).

Comment: I've never heard "your servant", but "at your service" is occasionally used in the U.S. It would only be appropriate in certain contexts, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Such expressions are not used, except ironically or to sound like an 18th century gentleman.

Don't use such expressions.  But of course a competent English speaker should recognize such language, understand it and understand the social and historic context that it implies.